# What is the difference between finite differences and divided differences?

Tags: terminology, finite-differences

Please clarify this. And if it is possible, write not only the formula, but where or in which cases each of them is used.

Comment: @mvw, yes, sure. I can't understand why we need divided differences, when we already have finite differences. Because finite differences give us the difference of values of function at two points.
But then why do we need divided difference? As I understood in divided difference we just take finite difference and divide by the difference of points, I mean by the distance. And if it so, then I can't understand what is the point of using it?

Comment: Divided differences is probably much older. If I remember correctly, from Newton already.

Comment: @mvw, yes, exactly! But in different sources these terms are used interchangeably (from first sight). In Russian books they use Finite Differences, but in English — Divided difference. And that's all okay, except that wikipedia gives two different articles for these terms. So it is confusing.